# How to display sql data in data grid view when a text and id is entered in a text box

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

[image: below is sql data in database.]

[image: This is my win form]

How to display sql data in the data grid view when a text is entered in text box.for eg:there is wai wai and britannia in dBase.I want to display all the information of data base in data grid column when product_name or product_id is entered in the Product Name: textbox.I've tried the following code: but its not working:

```
private void textBox2_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.KeyData==Keys.Enter)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SUMIT;Initial Catalog=Project;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter("select product_Name,product_Id,purchase_Price,discount,beforevat_Price,vat_Rate,actual_Cost,Margin,actual_Sp from Product", con);
        DataTable b = new DataTable();
        a.Fill(b);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = b;
        textBox3.Focus();
    }
}
```

it displays output like  below:
[image]

Comment: You should set column's **DataPropertyName** to bind to the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming your datagridview have no column set at start here (since we use datasource) try erase them.

```
 private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SUMIT;Initial Catalog=Project;Integrated Security=True " + "connection timeout=300");
            conn.Open();

            string query = "Select * from Product where product_Name  like '%"+textBox2.Text+"%'";
            SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter(query,conn);
            DataTable b = new DataTable();
            a.Fill(b);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = b;

        }
```

PS: if you absolutely want set column at start then don't use DataSource but 
use foreach loop on datatable b.rows then add the rows to datagridview1

```
DtataGridView1.Rows.Add(b["Product_Name],..,...)
```

2-like lei said you can use DataPropertyNametoo

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do it this way

```
string WhrCond = "";
int n;
if(int.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out n))
{
    WhrCond = "product_Id = " + textBox2.Text.Trim() ;
}
else
{
    WhrCond = "product_Name LIKE '%" + textBox2.Text.Trim() + "%'";
}

if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox2.Text))
{
    WhrCond = "1 = 1";
}
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SUMIT;Initial Catalog=Project;Integrated Security=True");
SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter("select product_Name as [Product Name],
                        actual_Cost as [Actual Cp], 
                        Margin, 
                        actual_Sp as [Actual SP], 
                        product_Id as [Product Id], 
                        purchase_Price as [Purchase Price], 
                        discount as [Discount], 
                        beforevat_Price as [Before Vat Price],
                        vat_Rate as [Vat%] from Product WHERE " + WhrCond , con);
DataTable b = new DataTable();
a.Fill(b);
dataGridView1.DataSource = b;
textBox3.Focus();
```

You shall be removing all the data from DGV created on the design time.

Comment: Mohit if(isNumeric(textBox2.Text)) isn't working.When I debug it displays isNumeric does not exist in current centext

Comment: not working.Its showing the same output as I have posted in above question.My datagrid view has columns,and when I press enter in text box2 it adds the same column in the data grid view.

Comment: You shall be removing all the data from DGV created on the design time.

Comment: No. I want the data to be displayed in the columns that i created in DGV.Eg If I press w in textbox2 then all the items starting from w should appear in the already designed columns of DGV,no additional columns.

Comment: I removed it and it worked.But it is displaying all the data from database.In data base I have wai wai and Britannia Marie.When I press w or any key it displays all the data from database.What I want was if i press w it should display wai wai and all other data starting from w and if I press b it should display britannia and all the data starting from b.

Comment: when i wrote this code in TextBox_Change event it showed an error and points to the code a.fill(b) please see through the code.

Comment: when i press w and press enter it shows:invalid syntax near w and points towards a.fill(b).

Comment: Got the Error: updated the answer and it should be `'%" + textBox2.Text.Trim() + "%'"`

Comment: You are most welcome. You can also say Thanks by upvoting and accepting the answer.

Comment: if you use datasource normaly your datagridview have to be empty of any column at start.if you have set column rigth start you can always fill the datagridview rows with a foreach loop tough

Comment: Hi @SumitBhattarai if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.